# Beginner to python facing 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute error

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to run a python code and this seems to cause error. Please help me

```
def randomPlace(b,lis):
    pos = []
    for i in lis:
        if available(b,i):
            pos.append(i)

    if len.pos() != 0:
        return random.choice(pos)
    else:
        return None
```

`b` is a list with 10 characters and `lis` is a list with 4 integers
Error is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "D:\TestsPython\TicTacToe.py", line 65, in randomPlace
>       if len.pos() != 0: AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'pos'

Comment: Did you mean `len(pos)`?

Comment: Oh , I feel so stupid, thank you, it worked

Answer (score 1):

The expression `len.pos()` asks the interpreter to locate `len` (the standard built-in function), look up its `pos` attribute (clue: it doesn't have one) and that call that looked up result. You actually want to apply the `len` function to the value of `pos`, and should therefore code

```
if len(pos) != 0:
```

Since len always returns an integer result, you could abbreviate this to

```
if len(pos):
```

Remembering, however. that empty containers evvaluate False in a Boolen context and non-empty containers evaluate True, it's usual to shorten this to

```
if pos:
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `len(pos)`.

In order to find the size of list in python, the syntax is `len(your_list)`.

In your case `len` function is not even required. You may simply do:

```
if pos:
    return random.choice(pos)
else:
    return None
```

Because if your list will have any element, `if` will consider it as `True`. In case of empty list, it will be treated as `False`.